# Has any recent academic research been done on the comparative performance of FOIA response speeds by different European governments?

Tags: european-union, foia, government

Recently, I took part in a large, international investigative journalistic [project](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/mar/22/revealed-ships-may-dump-oil-up-to-3000-times-a-year-in-europes-waters) on dumps of oily waste water by ships. In that context, I did a FOIA request to the Dutch government. Whereas the journalists that partook in the same investigation received the relevant documents pretty quickly in their respective countries when they sent out a similar request, I haven't received the information I asked for even after 8 months and a legal procedure with the administrative judge - who decided in my favour.

The inadequate response from the Dutch government in this case got me wondering about whether any systematic, academic research has been done on the comparative performance of FOIA response speeds by different European countries. I've tried finding recent and relevant scientific literature about this topic on - for instance - Google Scholar, but to no avail.

**Question**: are there any academic research papers that compare the response speed and adequateness of FOIA requests in different European countries, preferably including the Netherlands?

*Note*: I've also asked this [question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20360/has-any-recent-academic-research-been-done-on-the-comparative-performance-of-foi) on the Open Data SE page. This is my first question on the Law SE website - I hope it is appropriate.